# django in post_save signal DecimalField become float type

Tags: python, django, django-models

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save


class Order(models.Model):
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)


def post_save_order():
    if created:
        print(type(instance.total)) # here

post_save.connect(post_save_order, sender=Order)
```

I think the 'total' field shoule be Decimal type, but when I save a Order instance, it always print `<class 'float'>`

I know I can use 'decimal.Decimal' to convert it, I just wonder why it behaviors like this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `instance.total` retrieved from the database or did you populate it by hand (e.g. in a view using), using a `float`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I run `python3 manage.py shell` and  `new_order = Order.objects.create()`

Comment: Upon creation, it uses the default value of the field which you made a `float`. When you retrieve that instance form the database, you will see it is a `Decimal`. Saving does not update the types of instance attributes.

Comment: @schwobaseggl You are right, I changed the default to Decimal('0.00') and it works. Thank you!